# Replace comma in parentheses using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace comma when its inside   parentheses only.

For Example

```
 Progamming languages (Java, C#, Perl)
```

**TO**

```
Progamming languages (Java or C# or Perl)
```

but it should not repace comma in following string

```
Progamming languages Java, C#, Perl
```

CODE

It will replace correctly but its not matching up.

```
 String test  = "Progamming languages (Java, C#, Perl)";
 String test1 = "Progamming languages Java, C#, Perl"


 String foo = replaceComma(test);
 String foo1 = replaceComma(test1);


 private static String replaceComma(String test)
 {
    String patternStr= "\\((?:.*)(,)(?:.*)\\)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher matcher= pattern.matcher(test);

    if(matcher.matches())
    {
      return  test.replaceAll("(,)", " or ");
    }

    return  test;

 }
```

**UPDATE**

`String.replaceAll("(,)", " or ");` will not work when you have string like this

String test = "Learning, languages (Java, C#, Perl)";

so you have to use @polygenelubricants code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=…)` like this:

```
    String COMMA_INSIDE = ",(?=[^()]*\\))";
    String text = "a, b, c, (d, e, f), g, h, (i, j, k)";
    System.out.println(
        text.replaceAll(COMMA_INSIDE, " OR")
    );
    // a, b, c, (d OR e OR f), g, h, (i OR j OR k)
```

This matches a comma, but only if the first parenthesis to its right is of the closing kind.

The `[^…]` is a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). `[^()]` matches anything but parentheses. The `*` is zero-or-more [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). The `\)` (written as `"\\)"` as a Java string literal) matches a closing parenthesis, literally. The backslash escapes what is otherwise a special metacharacter for [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

This assumes that the input string is well-formed, i.e. parentheses are always balanced and not nested.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is using `matches` instead of `find` here:

```
if (matcher.find())
```

From the [documentation](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> - The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.
> - The find method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.

But your code also simplifies the issue somewhat - it replaces **all** commas even if only one of them is in parentheses. It's probably not a good idea to use regular expressions for this sort of task.

Instead you could scan the string one character at a time and count how many pairs of parentheses you are inside. When you see a `(` increase the count, and when you see a `)` decrease the count. If you see a `,` then check if the current count is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use positive lookahead and positive lookbehind in your regular expression.  That way you can search for commas that occur after a '(', but before a ')'.

`(?=X)` positive lookahead

`(?<=X)` positive lookbehind

Mark is correct you need a loop instead of replaceAll.  But you can still use a regular expression using the technique I've described.

Answer (score 0):

```
String  replaceComma(String input)
{
 String[] strSplit=input.split("[\\(\\)]");
  if(strSplit.length==2)
   input=input.replaceAll(", "," or ");
 return input;
}
```

**UPDATE**: *For String's like "Learning, languages (Java, C#, Perl)"*

```
String  replaceComma(String input)
{
String[] splitStr=input.split("[\\(\\)]");
 if(splitStr.length==2)
   input=input.replace(splitStr[1],splitStr[1].replaceAll(", ", " or "));
return input;
}
```

Comment: Poly's answer is better and a generic one.I'm just giving an alternative method.