# I want to replace ',' on the 150th location in a String with a <br>

Tags: regex

My String is : PI Last Name equal to one of

```
('AARONSON','ABDEL MEGUID','ABDEL-LATIF','ABDOOL KARIM','ABELL','ABRAMS','ACKERMAN','ADAIR','ADAMS','ADAMS-CAMPBELL', 'ADASHI','ADEBAMOWO','ADHIKARI','ADIMORA','ADRIAN', 'ADZERIKHO','AGADJANYAN','AGARWAL','AGOT', 'AGUIRRE-CRUZ','AHMAD','AHMED','AIKEN', 'AINAMO', 'AISENBERG','AJAIYEOBA','AKA','AKHTAR','AKINGBEMI','AKINYINKA','AKKERMAN','AKSOY','AKYUREK', 'ALBEROLA-ILA','ALBERT','ALCANTARA' ,'ALCOCK','ALEMAN', 'ALEXANDER','ALEXANDRE','ALEXANDROV','ALEXANIAN','ALLAND','ALLEN','ALLISON','ALPER', 'ALTMAN','ALVAREZ','AMARYAN','AMBESI-IMPIOMBATO','AMEGBETO','AMOWITZ', 'ANAGNOSTARAS','ANAND','ANDERSEN','ANDERSON', 'ANDRADE','ANDREEFF','ANDROPHY','ANGER','ANHOLT','ANTHONY','ANTLE','ANTONELLI','ANTONY', 'ANZULOVICH', 'APODACA','APOSHIAN','APPEL','APPLEBY','APRIL','ARAUJO','ARBIB','ARBOLEDA', 'ARCHAKOV','ARCHER', 'ARECHAVALETA-VELASCO','ARENS','ARGON','ARGYROKASTRITIS', 'ARIAS','ARIZAGA','ARMSTRONG','ARNON', 'ARSHAVSKY','ARVIN','ASATRYAN','ASCOLI','ASKENASE','ASSI','ATALAY','ATANASOVA','ATKINSON','ATTYGALLE','ATWEH','AU','AVETISYAN','AWE','AYOUB','AZAD','BACSO','BAGASRA','BAKER','BALAS', 'BALCAZAR','BALK','BALKAY','BALLOU','BALRAJ','BALSTER','BANERJEE','BANKOLE','BANTA','BARAL','BARANOWSKA','BARBAS', 'BARBER','BARILLAS-MURY','BARKHOLT','BARNES','BARNETT','BARRETT','BARRIA','BARROW','BARROWS','BARTKE','BARTLETT','BASSINGTHWAIGHTE','BASSIOUNY','BASU','BATES','BATTAGLIA','BATTERMAN','BAUER','BAUERLE','BAUM','BAUME', 'BAUMLER','BAVISTER','BAWA','BAYNE','BEASLEY','BEATTY','BEATY','BEBENEK','BECK','BECKER','BECKMAN','BECKMAN-SUURKULA' ,'BEDFORD','BEDOLLA','BEEBE','BEEMON','BEHETS','BEHRMAN','BEIER','BEKKER','BELL','BELLIDO','BELMAIN', 'BENATAR','BENBENISHTY','BENBROOK','BENDER','BENEDETTI','BENNETT','BENNISH','BENZ','BERG','BERGER','BERGEY','BERGGREN','BERK','BERKOWITZ','BERLIN','BERLINER','BERMAN','BERTINO','BERTOZZI','BERTRAND','BERWICK','BETHONY','BEYERS','BEYRER' ,'BEZPROZVANNY','BHAGWAT','BHANDARI','BHARGAVA','BHARUCHA','BHUJWALLA','BIANCO','BIDLACK','BIELERT','BIER','BIESSMANN','BIGELOW' ,'BILLER','BILLINGS','BINDER','BINDMAN','BINUTU','BIRBECK','BIRGE','BIRNBAUM','BIRO','BIRT','BISHAI','BISHOP','BISSELL','BJORKEGREN','BJORNSTAD','BLACK','BLANCHARD','BLASS','BLATTNER','BLIGNAUT','BLOCH','BLOCK','BLOOM','BLOOM,','BLUM','BLUMBERG' ,'BLUMENTHAL','BLYUKHER','BODDULURI','BOFFETTA','BOGOLIUBOVA', 'BOLLINGER','BOLLS','BOMSZTYK','BONANNO','BONNER','BOOM','BOOTHROYD','BOPPANA','BORAWSKI','BORG','BORIS-LAWRIE','BORISY','BORLONGAN','BORNSTEIN','BORODOVSKY','BORST','BOS','BOTO','BOWDEN','BOWEN','BOYCE-JACINO','BRADEN','BRADY' ,'BRAITHWAITE','BRANN','BRASH','BRAUNSTEIN', 'BREMAN','BRENNAN','BRENNER','BRETSCHER','BREW','BREYSSE','BRIGGS','BRITES','BRITT','BRITTENHAM','BRODIE','BRODY','BROOK','BROOTEN','BROSCO','BROSNAN','BROWN','BROWNE','BRUCKNER','BRUNENGRABER','BRYL','BRYSON','BU','BUCHAN','BUDD','BUDNIK', 'BUEKENS','BUKRINSKY','BULLMORE','BULUN','BURBANO','BURGENER','BURGESS','BURKS','BURMEISTER','BURNETT','BURNHAM','BURNS','BURRIDGE','BURTON','BUSCIGLIO','BUSHEK','BUSIJA','BUZSAKI','BZYMEK','CABA')
```

I need to have a regex which will greedily looks for up to 150 characters with a last character being a ','. And then replace the last ',' of the 150 with a `<br />`
Any suggestions pls?

I used this `','(?=[^()]*\))` but this one replaces all the occurences. I want the 150th ones to be replaced.

---

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I managed to do it with Java code instead of regex.

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(html);

        int i = 0; 
        while ((i = sb.indexOf("','", i + 150)) != -1) {

            int j = sb.lastIndexOf("','", i + 150);
            sb.insert(i+1, "<BR>"); 
        }

        return sb.toString();`

However, this breaks at the first encounter of ',' in the 150 chars.
Can anyone help modify my code to incorporate the break at the last occurence of ',' withing the 150 chars.

Comment: Now that you've created a question, please delete the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697139/replace-comma-in-parentheses-using-regex-in-java/4607660#4607660) you posted earlier.

Comment: @meagar: Unregistered users can't delete answers.

Comment: Further on down (as a comment to an answer) you're writing that your string actually is an entire HTML document, so you should clarify your question. How will we find the string inside this HTML document? Are you aware that applying regular expressions to HTML leads to madness? At least some people on StackOverflow think so :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this:

Look for every occurrence of `\([^)]+*,[^)]+*\)` (Find a parenthesis-wrapped string with a comma in it and then run the following regular expression on each of the matched elements:

```
(.{135,150}[^,]*?),
```

The first number is the *minimum* number of characters you want to match before you add a break tag -- the second is the *maximum* number of characters you would **like** to match before inserting a break tag.  If there is no `,` between the characters in question then the regular expression will continue to consume characters until it finds a comma.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Gives me error saying Unmatched closing ')' near index 17
(.{135,150})[^,]*?)','(points at ?)

Comment: @Viidhya -- Typo; I've fixed it now.  Give it another shot.

Comment: That worked.In the sense no compile errors. Thanks Sir.However didnt suffice my requirement. My String is actually an entire html doc containing several commas. It also has a substring which has values like I mentioned in my question in the beginning. I have to only append br within the parentheses characters at 150th location. I hope I am clearer. Can give you more info if needed. restricting due to char limitation. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I am not able to see the update. Still shows me (.{135,150}[^,]*?),

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it like this:

```
regex ~ /(^.{1,14}),/
replacement ~ '\1<replacement' or "$1<insert your text>"
```

In Perl:

```
$target = ','x 22;
$target =~ s/(^ .{1,14}) , /$1<15th comma>/x;
print $target;

Output
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,<15th comma>,,,,,,,
```

**Edit:** As an alternative, if you want to break the string up into succesive 150 or less
you could do it this way:

```
regex ~ /(.{1,150},)/sg
replacement ~ '\1<br/>' or "$1<br\/>"
// That is a regex of type global (/g) and include newlines (/s)
```

In Perl:

```
$target = "

('AARONSON','ABDEL MEGUID','ABDEL-LATIF','ABDOOL KARIM','ABELL','ABRAMS','ACKERMAN','ADAIR','ADAMS','ADAMS-CAMPBELL', 'ADASHI','ADEBAMOWO','ADHIKARI','ADIMORA','ADRIAN', 'ADZERIKHO','AGADJANYAN','AGARWAL','AGOT', 'AGUIRRE-CRUZ','AHMAD','AHMED','AIKEN', 'AINAMO', 'AISENBERG','AJAIYEOBA','AKA','AKHTAR','AKINGBEMI','AKINYINKA','AKKERMAN','AKSOY','AKYUREK', 'ALBEROLA-ILA','ALBERT','ALCANTARA' ,'ALCOCK','ALEMAN', 'ALEXANDER','ALEXANDRE','ALEXANDROV','ALEXANIAN','ALLAND','ALLEN','ALLISON','ALPER', 'ALTMAN', ... )

    ";

if ($target =~ s/( .{1,150} , )/$1<br\/>/sxg) {
    print $target;
}
```

Output:

```
('AARONSON','ABDEL MEGUID','ABDEL-LATIF','ABDOOL KARIM','ABELL','ABRAMS','ACKERMAN','ADAIR','ADAMS','ADAMS-CAMPBELL', 'ADASHI','ADEBAMOWO','ADHIKARI',<br/>'ADIMORA','ADRIAN', 'ADZERIKHO','AGADJANYAN','AGARWAL','AGOT', 'AGUIRRE-CRUZ','AHMAD','AHMED','AIKEN', 'AINAMO', 'AISENBERG','AJAIYEOBA','AKA',<br/>'AKHTAR','AKINGBEMI','AKINYINKA','AKKERMAN','AKSOY','AKYUREK', 'ALBEROLA-ILA','ALBERT','ALCANTARA' ,'ALCOCK','ALEMAN', 'ALEXANDER','ALEXANDRE',<br/>'ALEXANDROV','ALEXANIAN','ALLAND','ALLEN','ALLISON','ALPER', 'ALTMAN',<br/> ... )
```